# Embed manifest with C Extension dll using distutil

Tags: python, windows, manifest, msvcrt

What is the preferred way to embed a manifest with a C Extension DLL when I generate it through distutil. 
Currently when I build a C Extension as part of the distutil process, it creates a manifest and the corresponding *.pyd but when I check the dependency using dependency walker,

[image]

But if I manually embed the manifest

```
mt -manifest jep.pyd.manifest -outputresource:jep.pyd;2
Microsoft (R) Manifest Tool version 6.2.9200.16384
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2012.
All rights reserved.
```

The dependency gets satisfied

[image]

What is the suggested way to overcome the manual process to embed the manifest. Can this be done through distutil automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python extension DLLs are not expected to have the MSVCR manifest. You can take a look at the extension DLLs that ship with Python (e.g. _bz2.pyd, _ctypes.pyd, _lzma.pyd, _tkinter.pyd etc.) and you will see that they do not contain a manifest resource.